# What OAuth2.0 flow to use to secure my Rest API?

Tags: oauth-2.0, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I have a Rest API that is used by different clients:

- Browser, when using swagger
- Postman, when calling API
- Curl
- Other HttpClients, jvm, Python and such.

I want all clients to get authenticated with Azure AD. So each of them has to have an email, authenticate itself in front of Azure AD and then pass some token to my Rest API, on the backend I will validate the token. I really don't understand which flow to use. The one that is closest to my scenario seems to be Credentials Flow but I still don't understand how it fits in.
This picture is what I am trying to achieve: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The OAuth 2.0 **On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO)** serves the use case where an application invokes a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API. The idea is to propagate the delegated user identity and permissions through the request chain. For the middle-tier service to make authenticated requests to the downstream service, it needs to secure an access token from the Microsoft identity platform, on behalf of the user.

Based on your scenario it is recommended to use [On-Behalf-Of flow (OBO)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow).